# Why does my cat scratch so much against the sides of his litter box?

Tags: behavior, cats

While I understand cats and their desire to bury their waste when they are finished, my cat often sits in the litter box and digs against the plastic side of the litter box, not actually in the litter itself, so much so that he is actually wearing down the sides in places.

Why is he doing this? Is it a problem (other than the destruction of the litter box)?

Comment: Is there more than one cat in this situation or just one?

Comment: Just the one. :)

Comment: I don't think this is worthy of a complete answer, but this most likely has to do with marking territory, as you know big cats do this by scratching trees and stuff in the wild, so I'm assuming it might have to do with a territorial thing.

Comment: My indoor cat uses her declawed front paws to rub the side of the box. Probably similar behavior.

Comment: Your cat's just some kind of crazy :)

Comment: Some cats dig like maniacs, some just plop and go.  Different strokes.

Comment: I posted the question, and the more I think about it, the more I think my cat is crazy!

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely a combination of marking his territory (aka the litter box), and also possibly cleaning off his paws from the litter that gets in-between the pads. It's not really a problem, because trying to stop it could give the cat an aversion to the litter box, which results in the cat using anything else as a litter box.

It could also be that the cat is entertaining himself by digging in the litter.